# How to define function call in nmake?

Tags: makefile, nmake

I'm translating a GNU makefile to nmake. It defines function as below:

```
define pull_container
    docker pull projectunik/$(1):$(shell jq '.["$(1)"]' containers/versions.json)
endef
```

Then function can be called like:

```
$(call pull_container,vsphere-client)
```

The real argument `vsphere-client` will be substituted into the 1st parameter: `$(1)`. Is there any alternative for `nmake`?

Comment: No.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/build/nmake-reference  I mean, you have to write it out by hand everywhere.

Comment: Thanks. I'm also afraid there's no other way.